# Any finitely many points in $P^n$ can be included in an affine open chart

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-varieties

Let $\mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective space over an algebraic closed field $k$. I want to show that any finitely many points in $\mathbb{P}^n$ can be included in an affine open chart of it. A candidate would be the principal open set i.e. the complement of a hypersurface $\mathbb{P}^n-V(f)$ which is affine. However, I have trouble constructing this homogeneous polynomial $f$ i.e. given finitely many points $a_0, a_1,...\in \mathbb{P}^n$ then $a_0,a_1,...\not\in V(f)$. The only thought I have is to look at them on an affine chart and I can construct an $f'$ in affine space, and then homogenize it. However, this will make me circular i.e. I come back to find an affine chart that includes those points. So I guess this won't work.

Appreciate any ideas or hints!

Comment: For a bit of a higher-level solution using prime avoidance (plus some good discussion), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256648/open-affine-neighborhood-of-points). There are also more basic solutions (linear algebra, good choices of coordinates, etc) if you're interested in those. Would you like me to mark this as a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: @KReiser Please feel free to do so. Would you mind pointing out the link for the elementary solutions as we haven't talked about scheme yet?

Answer (score 1):

A fairly direct way to see this is via duality: we search for a hyperplane $H \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ such that $a_1,\dots,a_m \notin H$ - the complement of $H$ will thus contain $a_1,\dots,a_m$ and be isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n_k$.

If, by contradiction, every hyperplane $H$ contained $a_i$ for some $i$, then - passing to ${\mathbb{P}^n_k}^\ast \cong \mathbb{P}_k^n$ - we get that every point in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is contained in at least one of the $m$-many hyperplanes corresponding to $a_1,\dots,a_m \implies \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a union of $m$ hyperplanes, which of course contradicts the fact the $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ has dimension $n > n-1$.